# inserting a row into a table and bumping up the auto increment values that come after

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to find out the correct way to do this via googling but I am not finding anything helpful.

I am wanting to insert a row before id 60 and `id` is an auto incrementing value. In the end I want to have all the values of `id` to be bumped up by 1 so there isn't a collision on the primary key of `id`.

[image: Current Database structure]

Comment: Be careful that this might break your foreign keys and/or cause your data to become inconsistent. It is usually a better idea to add an extra `sort_sequence` column that is only used for ordering and keeping the `id` column untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this::

Step1:

```
update table set id=id+1 where id>=60
```

Step2:

```
Insert into table(id, column1....) values (60,....)
```